# How can I make min_element catch ALL points with the lowest value?

Tags: c++, algorithm, grahams-scan

I'm writing a program to calculate the perimeter of a convex hull using the [graham scan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan) and need to find the lowest y coordinate in a set of data points. I'm using `std::min_element(vector.begin(), vector.end())` with an overloaded `<` operator in my struct `point`. The problem is that some points may share the same lowest y coordinate, and in that case I need to compare them using their x values. Is there any quick cheat to check if any other points are sharing the same y as the min_element without having to loop through everything?

struct:

```
struct cord{
        cord():x(0),y(0){}
        int x,y;
        bool operator<(const cord &p) const { return y < p.y; }
};

typedef std::vector<cord>::iterator vecIter;
```

function call:

```
vecIter lowestPoint =
                std::min_element(points.begin(), points.end());

std::cout << "the lowest point of the data set is: " << "(" <<
                lowestPoint->x << "," << lowestPoint->y << ")"  << std::endl;
```

Comment: Just change your `operator<` to form a `std::tuple` or `std::pair` out of `y` and `x` and let that do the comparison for you.

Comment: If you're absolutely married to your `cord` object class, use [`std::tie(x,y) < std::tie(p.x,p.y)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) in your `operator <()`.

Comment: Are you trying to find the minimum `x` for the minimum `y`, or all points with the minimum `y`? Your title points to the latter, but your question body points to the former.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, just something like this? (to replace your existing `operator<` function)

```
bool operator<(const cord &p) const
{
   if (y != p.y)
     return y < p.y;
   else
     return x < p.x;
}
```